# How to manage the no error case when handling errors in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I need to catch some VBA errors using the `GoTo` statement:

```
Sub mySub
 On Error GoTo errorHandler:
    Workbooks.Open("myWorkbook")
'
' Some Code
'
errorHandler:
MsgBox "ERROR"

End Sub
```

The problem is that when there is no error the `errorHandler` section is executed.
I found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099177/why-vba-goes-to-error-handling-code-when-there-is-no-error) but the answer doesn't solve my issue.
I tried adding an `Exit Sub` statement as explained :

```
Sub mySub
 On Error GoTo errorHandler:
    Workbooks.Open("myWorkbook")
    Exit Sub

'
' Some Code
'
errorHandler:
  MsgBox "ERROR"

End Sub
```

In this case it exits the method when there is no error.
I also tried :

```
 Sub mySub
 On Error GoTo errorHandler:
    Workbooks.Open("myWorkbook")
'
' Some Code
'
errorHandler:
  MsgBox "ERROR"
  Exit Sub
End Sub
```

But still the same issue: The `errorHandler` is executed even when no errors occur.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just put Exit sub in.

```
Sub mySub
 On Error GoTo myHandler:
    Workbooks.Open("myWorkbook")
'
' Some Code
'
Exit sub

myHandler:
MsgBox "EROOR !"

err.clear
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add the line `On Error Goto 0`? So OP understands that it's a good practice resetting error redirects... Upvoted :)

Comment: @Marco Do you mean err.Clear? This is VBA.

Comment: @Marco should i reset it after each catching bloc ?
`On Error GoTo myHandler:
    Workbooks.Open("myWorkbook")
On Error GoTo 0`

Comment: @Remou: maybe I'm wrong, but I remember I used (many years ago) `On Error Goto 0` to make code behave without error checking. And I remember it was a good practice to use this instruction to avoid unpredictable *jumps* for later errors... I searched Google to see if I was wrong, but [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm) I found an article giving me `On Error Goto 0`...

Comment: @M3HD1: no, you should reset when you're sure you cannot have other errors (when you don't want to manage them) and before exiting sub. Don't take my advice as a rule because it's not... it's something I remember as a good practice to avoid headaches....

Comment: @Marco You can use On Error GoTo 0, but it is not standard practice with an error handler, as you can see in the example posted in your link.

Comment: @Marco: I see no reason to use `On Error GoTo 0`, and I've never seen it in an error handler either... I've seen it in an `ExitProcedure:` type thing ([example](http://www.xoc.net/standards/rvbacc.asp#ErrorHandling)) to avoid infinite error handling "loops".

Comment: On Error GoTo 0 turns error handling OFF, tells VB/VBA to stop and throw up an error message if an error is encountered.  It also (implicitly) clears the error condition.  In a simple case like this, there's probably no disadvantage to using it but in other cases where you'd want to trap an error, deal with it then resume processing, you definitely wouldn't want to use GoTo 0.  And even in this simple case, there's no advantage to it; on the whole, a bad habit to get into, I'd say.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg `On Error Goto 0` doesn't always throw up an error message; if there is an On Error statement in effect anywhere up the call stack, that error handler will kick in first.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the pattern I prefer:

```
Sub SomeSub()
    On Error GoTo ErrorLabel

    'Code goes here

ExitLabel:
   'Clean-up code, if any, goes here 
   Exit Sub

ErrorLabel:
    'Error-handling code goes here
    Resume ExitLabel
End Sub
```

Note that `Resume` clears the error.  I like this pattern for a few reasons:

1. Habitually inserting the exit block *before* the error-handling block reduces the chance that I'll have the OP's problem of accidentally dropping into the error handler.
2. I use `GoTo ExitLabel` for *any* early exit from the Sub or Function.  This way, I'm less likely to skip the clean-up code by accident.  Example:

   ```
   Sub SomeOtherSub()
       Dim x As ResourceThatNeedsToBeClosed
       Dim i As Long
       On Error GoTo ErrorLabel
       Set x = GetX
       For i = 1 To 100
           If x.SomeFunction(i) Then
               GoTo ExitLabel
           End If
       Next
   ExitLabel:
       x.Close
   ErrorLabel:
       'Error-handling code goes here
       Resume ExitLabel
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Yes, I prefer this too. It seems to be the standard for apps that automatically insert error handling blocks as well. I even have a little code to remove and to create outline error handling in this format.

Answer (score 2):

```
Public Sub MySub
    On Error Goto Skip

    ' Some Codes

Skip:
    If err.Number > 0 Then

        ' Run whatever codes if error occurs

        err.Clear
    End If
    On Error Goto 0
End Su
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in error handler section:

```
if err.number>0 the
    ' error handling goes here
else
    ' some code
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same issue as you, and the solutions above did not work. They clearly didn't even see you wrote Exit Sub in already in 2 different places in your original post. No site online seems to understand that sometimes there won't be an error (if there was always going to be an error, why did you code it that way?), and when there isn't an error, you obviously don't want to Exit Sub. Nor do you want the myHandler to run when there isn't an error. DUH! This is the solution I cam up with which seems to work.

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
'This is the thing I am trying to do...
Workbooks("SpreadSolver.xlsb").Activate
'If it works, great. 
'Don't touch the error stuff and move on. 
'I.e. go to the part that I know works (the rest of the macro)
GoTo ThisPartWorks

'If the thing I am trying to do doesn't work...
ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Error: Please open Spread Solver and then run the macro."
'Only want to Exit Sub if there is an error.. duh.
Exit Sub

ThisPartWorks:
'the rest of your macro can go here...
'...
End Sub
```

Comment: The accepted answer should work whether there's an error or not, and this is actually the right way to handle errors in VBA. On the other hand, using `GoTo` to move around code is considered very bad practice, especially if you will be using multiple `GoTo` statements.

Comment: The OP put `Exit Sub` in two wrong different places. You just need to put it in the right place (i.e right before your error handling code).

Answer (score 0):

I use an If statement, within the ErrorHandler, which will stop execution if there is no error. This is achieved by using the Err.Number (Err (object) number (e.g. Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range))

```
If Err.Number >= 1 Then
MsgBox ("Message")
End
Else: other code
End If
Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done. Works like a charm

```
Sub someProgram ()
    On Error goto Handler:
        x = 7/0

    'Some code you wanna execute  with or without error
Exit Sub

Handler:
     'Write your handler here

Resume next 'After handling error, this line will help you resume the next line

End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sub XYZ ()
on error goto label

"Write your macro"

Label:
      If Err.Description <> "" Then
       "your code if error occurs for eg:"
       msgbox "Error Occured!"
       Exit Sub
       Else
       "Your code when no error occurs for eg"
        msgbox " Done."
       End If
Exit Sub
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.