# Error handling when opening a file

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have the following code:

Sub patch()

```
Dim r As Long, j As Long, c As Long
Dim day As Long, month As Long, year As Long


year = 2014

    For month = 2 To 2 Step -1

        For day = 12 To 1 Step -1

            On Error GoTo nextday
            Workbooks.Open ("G:\Manu\PVA\Pmo_Multiprogrammes\10-Process & Tools\00 GESTION DE CHANGEMENT\03 AMÉLIORER\20 Base de données\00 Mproduct\19-Suivi\Suivi du Cseries\rapport quotidien\Suivi Cseries_" & day & "_" & month & "_" & year & ".xlsm")
            On Error GoTo 0

            '## Do stuff

            Workbooks("Suivi Cseries_" & day & "_" & month & "_" & year & ".xlsm").Close (False)

nextday:
        Next 'day

    Next 'mont

End Sub
```

When a file can not be found I just want the cofe to continue with the next file thus why I put "One Error GoTo nextday" but it does not work. I still get the file not found pop up and the the debug pop up appears too. There must be something I'm missing.

Comment: yes the same thing happens. It still just debugs. I also checked in the settings tools->Option->General->Break on unhandled errors is selected

Comment: Have a look at [this too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141292/error-handling-vba-when-no-errors)

Comment: ah this works too but just like the other answer only half way. it doesn't pop up the debug window but it does do the excel pop up that says file not found. I have to press OK for every missing file. Can I prevent this too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this pattern:

```
Sub patch()

    Dim r As Long, j As Long, c As Long
    Dim myDay As Long, myMonth As Long, myYear As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False       

    myYear = 2014

    For myMonth = 2 To 2 Step -1    
        For myDay = 12 To 1 Step -1

            On Error Resume Next
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open("G:\Manu\PVA\Pmo_Multiprogrammes\10-Process & Tools\00 GESTION DE CHANGEMENT\03 AMÉLIORER\20 Base de données\00 Mproduct\19-Suivi\Suivi du Cseries\rapport quotidien\Suivi Cseries_" & myDay & "_" & myMonth & "_" & myYear & ".xlsm")
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not wb Is Nothing Then
                '## Do stuff
                wb.Close False
            End If
        Next 'day
    Next 'mont

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

**BTW**, don't use variables with specific names such as `day`, `month`, `year` sicne in that case VBA functions with this names (`DAY()`, `MONTH()`, `YEAR()`) won't work

Comment: this works half way. it doesn't pop up the debug window but it does do the excel pop up that says file not found. I have to press OK for every missing file. Can I prevent this too?

Comment: @user2385809, try now. It doesn't show any messages for me

Comment: @user2385809, `but it does do the excel pop up that says file not found` - I think it's related with the code you didn't include in question. My current code can't trigger any pop-up messages. Show please full code